# Why am I not routing through the Switch? React Router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am using React Router 4 and am not routing through a nested `Switch` component.  Here are my routes:

```
const routes = (
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" >
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/test" component={Test} />
          <Route path="/other" component={Other} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        </Switch>
      </Route>
      <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
);
```

I hit the root `/` route, but if I try to route to any of the other nested routes `/about`, `/other`, `/test`, I go to my error page.  I assume it is because I have `exact` on the `Route` with the root `/` route, but I am not sure.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation says,

> Switch renders the first child  or  that matches the
>   location.

In your case the outer switch has to choose between 2 , the exact path="/" and *...so it will match always with the NotFound except when path is exactly "/"
That's why you should remove the exact from the line 4 and move the `<Route path="*" component={NotFound} />` inside the inner switch.

For your case I'd write something like:

```
const routes = (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Index} />
      <Route exact={true} path="/test" component={Test} />
      <Route exact={true}  path="/other" component={Other} />
      <Route exact={true} path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
);
```

You can check these files from my working example:
https://github.com/sstawecki/polakete/blob/master/client/src/index.js
https://github.com/sstawecki/polakete/blob/master/client/src/Routes.js

Comment: The first `Switch` is always going to route to the first `Route`.  The router will never route to the `NotFound` `Route`.

Comment: You're right, I've updated the answer, the structure depends on how is going to be your page layout, I shared my example due to I have the header and footer in separated routes and the switch with all the routes in another component, including the NotFound route. Nested switches weren't needed for now.

Comment: I need to have the multiple `Switch`'s.  Basically, if you have access, you will be allowed into the first `Route` of the first `Switch`, else you will go to the `Not Found` page.  If you make it through the first `Switch`, then you will be allowed to navigate around the second `Switch`.

Comment: Well, but <Route exact path="/" >  has inner Switch with components which have a path like ``/something``, but the parent says "exact /", so they will never match in the inner switch. You have to remove the exact in order to make sense render the inner Switch...and the inner switch has to match with something, otherwise it won't render anything...that's why you have to include a NotFound inside the inner switch if you want.